# Наполнение коллекции MongoBD из текстового файла с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Есть текстовый файл, каждую строчку из него надо записывать в базу MongoDB.
Для этого создаю словарь, где на 3ю позицию записываю сточку из файла.
Затем сформированный словарь надо записать в базу MongoDB.
Словарь у меня формируется нормально (пока не победил только символ переноса строки),но записывается в базу только последняя строка,которая была в текстовом файле

```
# импорт в MyDb - Specializations

import datetime

# Create the client
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client['MyDb']
series_collection = db['Specializations']

# читаем текстовый файл и количество строк. строку вписываем в ключ Name

dicts = {'DateTime': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
         'DateTimeLastChange': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

with open('names.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    for i in f:
        dicts[3] = i
        dicts["Name"] = dicts.pop(3)
        print(dicts)
        series_collection.insert_many([dicts])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# импорт в MyDb - Specializations

import datetime

# Create the client
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client['MyDb']
series_collection = db['Specializations']

# читаем текстовый файл и количество строк. строку вписываем в ключ Name

with open('names.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    for i in f:
        #надо было сюда добавить создание словаря
        dicts = {'DateTime': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
         'DateTimeLastChange': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
        dicts[3] = i
        dicts["Name"] = dicts.pop(3)
        print(dicts)
        series_collection.insert_many([dicts])
```